# How to host a reactjs app on nginx web server?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, web-hosting

I have had previous experience deploying my react app to firebase and hosting it with that but I have no clue how to deploy my react app to an nginx web server since this is a project with a friend and they are hosting the web server.

Comment: [nginx react tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+react+tutorial) contains some great info out there already. I recommend returning here with specific questions/problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using create-react-app or nextjs, you can build your app and deploy the static files.

`npm run build`
`npm start`

If you need something like node running for auth or something else, you can use node express as the server and then nginx also.  Lots of discussions about pros and cons.

https://www.quora.com/Should-I-host-a-node-js-project-without-nginx